# Javascript transform array into grouped object by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array:

```
["car1-coupe", "car2-convertible", "car2-hatchback", "car2-estate", "car3-hatchback", "car3-estate"]
```

The array can have different sets of cars, and I want to turn it into something like this:

```
[{
    car1: ["car1-coupe"]
},{
    car2: ["car2-convertible", "car2-hatchback", "car2-estate"]
},{
    car3: ["car3-hatchback", "car3-estate"]
}]
```

How can I do this in JavaScript or Underscore?

Comment: Do you absolutely need that output? Or can it be slightly different?

Comment: By looping yourself or using map() which will loop internally

Comment: You want to turn it into "something like" that or you want to turn it into precisely that? I don't know why you'd store it that way, personally; seems like it would make more sense to have a single object (abandoning the wrapping array) with three properties: car1, car2 and car3.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Iterating over the array? Splitting a string? Adding properties to an object? You matt have tried something and got stuck somewhere... what is it?

Comment: @Cerbrus the output can be different as long as I have the models grouped by cars. Felix My problem is about the grouping

Answer (score 2):

So, assuming an array like this:

```
var a = ["car1-coupe", "car2-convertible", "car2-hatchback", "car2-estate", "car3-hatchback", "car3-estate"];
```

You can do this:

```
var b = a.reduce(function(prev, curr){
    var car = curr.split('-')[0]; // "get" the current car
    prev[car] = prev[car] || [];  // Initialize the array for the current car, if necessary.
    prev[car].push(curr);         // Add the current item to the array.
    return prev;
}, {});
```

This will return the following object:

```
{
    car1: ["car1-coupe"],
    car2: ["car2-convertible", "car2-hatchback", "car2-estate"],
    car3: ["car3-hatchback", "car3-estate"]
}
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately needs to work in IE8, `reduce()` is works in IE9 onwards, sorry forgot to mention it.

Comment: @Mauro74 you can easily add a shim.

Comment: No worries, you can find a [polyfill for `reduce()` on the MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Polyfill).

Comment: Ok @Cerbrus I'll use the Polyfill!

Comment: With the polyfill in place, does this answer (and it's output) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = ["car1-coupe", "car2-convertible", "car2-hatchback", "car2-estate", "car3-hatchback", "car3-estate"];

var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var key = array[i].split('-')[0]; // The car we're interested in
  if (result[key]) { // Check if this car has already been initialized
    result[key].push(array[i]); //add this model to the list
  } else {
    result[key] = [array[i]]; // initialize the array with the first value
  }
}

console.log(result);
/*will return :
{
  car1: ["car1-coupe"],
  car2: ["car2-convertible", "car2-hatchback", "car2-estate"],
  car3: ["car3-hatchback", "car3-estate"]
}
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var  myObj = {}, myArr = [];
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1) {
      var key = arr[i].split("-")[0];
      myObj = {};
      myObj[key] = [];
      for( var j = i; j < arr.length; j+=1 ) {
            if( key === arr[j].split("-")[0])
                myObj[key].push(arr[j]);
      }
      myArr.push(myObj);
}
```

I think this can be done simply with this way. One loop to get the key and another inner loop to get all values of this key.

Comment: Waaaaaaay too many temporary variables, 2 loops, and no explanation at all. -1